# localStorage only set after refreshing the page

Tags: extjs

i'm trying to auto login into an app. So i set some localStorage items in the Login controller.

```
localStorage.setItem("session", me.sessionToken);
localStorage.setItem("loggedin", true);
```

And my app.js looks like that

```
launch: function() {
        if(!localStorage.getItem("loggedin")){
        Ext.Viewport.add([
            { xtype: 'loginview' },
            { xtype: 'main' }
         ]);
        } else {
            Ext.Viewport.add([
            { xtype: 'main' },
            { xtype: 'loginview' }
         ]);
        }   
}
```

This works fine. But the first time i show the loginview view after my first login, the localStorage is not set. It says my session is null and my loggedin is null. I have to refresh the page, then it's all set and i can see the values of my localStorage.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: localStorage is updated immediately, so your getter is happening before your setter

Comment: That means there's no was to use this for the login authentication without refreshing the page? localStorage.clear();window.location.reload(); before settings the new values works ... but it doesn't look nice.

Comment: Could you not authenticate/set the session on a separate page, then redirect to the authenticated page?

Comment: that's what i do. I authenticate the login with a php script. If i get the response success = true then the user will be redirected to the main view else he will be redirected to the login view again. This works fine. But if I want to use the localStorage it's just null. So I have to reload the page to see the values.